# How to show date picker value in a label and textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

I am using this function

and its box of input is

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fulldate" class="form-control wid-100"> <span id="#dpicker_name"></span>
```

Please help me in it friends

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: what's the issue here? did you see any errors in `console`?

Comment: check your jquery file is included or not?

Comment: Venugopal No i am not getting any error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          $("#dpicker_name").html(dateText);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">

<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fulldate" class="form-control wid-100"> 
<span id="dpicker_name"></span>
```

Please check [Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Also you can get it without `onSelect` like

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
```

Answer (score 0):

used to this code

**Demo**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    
  });
    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#datepicker').on('change', function(){
        var dateThis = $(this).val();
        $('#dpicker_name').text(dateThis);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> <span id="dpicker_name"></span></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be api docs for labels datepicker can make it more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#dpicker_name").text($( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" ));
```

Comment: can u please tell me what is a selector in it

Comment: @Harsimransingh i will update code as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get value in `javascript` as

```
var date = $(".datepicker").val();
```

and assigned it to the `lable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
   });
```

Seems to me you want to trigger the datepicker on click of icon. [Check the docs here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) .